# How to fix the HCF only being found if the numbers are equal

Tags: javascript, function

I am creating a code to find the highest common factor of two numbers, however, the code will always return 'undefined', unless the two numbers given as parameters to the function are equal.

I have tried several numerical inputs, such as (3,6), (6,12), (7,11), and others similar, all of which returned 'undefined'.

```
function HCF_Finder (num1, num2) {
  var i = 1;
  let factors1 = [];
  let factors2 = []
  while (i <= Math.ceil(num1 / 2)) {
    if (num1 % i == 0) {
      factors1.push(i);
    }
    i ++
  }
  i = 1;
  while (i <= Math.ceil(num2 / 2)) {
    if (num2 % i == 0) {
      factors2.push(i);
    }
    i ++;
  }
  factors1.push(num1);
  factors2.push(num2);
  if (num1 == num2) {
    return (num1);
  } else if (num1 < num2) {
    for (x = 1; x < factors1.length + 1; x ++) {
      if (factors2.includes(factors1[-1 * x])) {
        return (factors1[-1 * x]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (x = 1; x < factors2.length + 1; x ++) {
      if (factors1.includes(factors2[-1 * x])) {
        return (factors2[-1 * x]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The expected output of (3,5) should be 1, but is undefined.
The expected output of (6,12) should be 6, but is undefined.

Comment: What's with this `-1 * x`? That's really weird. Why not use a normal loop and array index?

Answer (score 0):

What's with using negative index inside array. Small change in your code should fix this. The reason for undefined is because you are using negative index value inside array.
Change your elseIf block to something below

```
let length = factors1.length;
    for (x = 1; x < length + 1; x ++) {
      if (factors2.includes(factors1[length-x])) {
        return (factors1[length-x]);
      }
    }
```

The same goes for else block too. Also I would suggest to try eucledian algorithm to find HCF. It is much elegant and smaller than the code you have already written